# One pixel between two UITableViewCellStyleDefault cells -- Can't draw over it

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I want to draw 2 buttons in one cell and when the button is pressed, the blue image will cover half of the cell.

But there is 1 pixel I can't draw.

Here is the situation:

[image]

And the code:

```
[self addGood12ToView:cell.contentView productDetail:productDetail];
```

In this function, I called:

```
UIButton *lbGood1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[lbGood1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, lbGood1_Size.height+19)];
...
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbGood1];
```

Comment: I wonder, why +19 ? See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460510/how-do-i-prevent-a-one-pixel-border-in-variable-height-uitableviewcell-from-comi You might want to round the button size to the higher round.

Comment: @A-Live 19 is meaningless. My question is the frame's origin is (0,0). But there is one line on the Bottom.

Comment: @Eout that's correct, but it's so hard to read the code with the literals instead of constants. See the updated comment above. I'd round both the cell and button height to be sure there's control over drawing, i guess you are using `lbGood1_Size` to calculate both.

Comment: @A-Live I got it, thank you. Can I have your gtalk that I can ask you question on iOS?

Comment: @Eout You can find a lot of help at SO chat rooms, search for iOs tagged rooms there: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with this may be help full to you.

```
self.yourTableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

change Single Line Etched to "separator: Single Line" in the inspector. Good luck

Edit 1
from Apple doc

ell Separator Style
The style for cells used as separators.

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone,
    UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine,
    UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched
} UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle;
```

Constants

```
UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone
```

The separator cell has no distinct style.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in `UITableViewCell.h.`

```
UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine
```

The separator cell has a single line running across its width. This is the default value
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in `UITableViewCell.h`.

```
UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched
```

**The separator cell has double lines running across its width, giving it an etched look. This style is currently only supported for grouped-style table views.**

Comment: what's the separatorStyle of your setting? UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched right?